# Assign Quantile Bins to Variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the pandas .qcut() function to divide a column 'AveragePrice' into 4 bins. I would like to assign each bin to a new variable. The reason for this is to do a separate analysis on each quartile. IE) I would like something like:

```
bin1 = quartile 1

bin2= quartile 2 

bin3 = quartile 3 

bin4= quantile 4
```

Here is what I'm working with.

```
`pd.qcut(data['AveragePrice'], q=4)`

2        (0.439, 1.1]
3        (0.439, 1.1]
17596     (1.1, 1.38]
17600     (1.1, 1.38]

Name: AveragePrice, Length: 14127, dtype: category

Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(0.439, 1.1] < (1.1, 1.38] < (1.38, 1.69] < (1.69, 3.25]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can ["pivot"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) your quartile values into columns.

Toy example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'AveragePrice': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=10) })
```

|  | AveragePrice |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 |
| 1 | 29 |
| 2 | 53 |
| 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 78 |
| 7 | 62 |
| 8 | 75 |
| 9 | 1 |

Create the `Quartile` column, pivot `Quartile` into columns, and rename the columns to something more reader-friendly:

```py
df['Quartile'] = pd.qcut(df.AveragePrice, q=4)
pivot = df.reset_index().pivot_table(
    index='index',
    columns='Quartile',
    values='AveragePrice')
pivot.columns = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']
```

|  | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | 20.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | NaN | 29.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | 53.0 | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | 30.0 | NaN |
| 4 | 3.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | 4.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 6 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 78.0 |
| 7 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 62.0 |
| 8 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 75.0 |
| 9 | 1.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Now you can analyze the bins separately, e.g., `describe` them:

```py
pivot.describe()
```

|  | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| count | 3.000000 | 2.000000 | 2.000000 | 3.000000 |
| mean | 2.666667 | 24.500000 | 41.500000 | 71.666667 |
| std | 1.527525 | 6.363961 | 16.263456 | 8.504901 |
| min | 1.000000 | 20.000000 | 30.000000 | 62.000000 |
| 25% | 2.000000 | 22.250000 | 35.750000 | 68.500000 |
| 50% | 3.000000 | 24.500000 | 41.500000 | 75.000000 |
| 75% | 3.500000 | 26.750000 | 47.250000 | 76.500000 |
| max | 4.000000 | 29.000000 | 53.000000 | 78.000000 |

Comment: This makes sense. I appreciate it. One more question. Is it possible for me to just add a column to my original dataframe that says what quartile that row falls in?

Comment: Yep I edited the answer to store the pivot table now as `pivot` instead of overwriting `df`. That way you'll still have access to the new `Quartile` column in `df`.